# Disable drawing on black pixels

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a fabric.js canvas that contains an image object like this:
[image]

I can draw on that image with several colors/brushes, but I **don't** want to draw over the black lines/pixels. This is because it describes the walls on my image.

So if I e.g. draw some red on the canvas, it should look like this:

[image]

As you can see, the black lines should persist. But the big question is: How do I do that in fabric.js?

I can think of two solutions:

1. Find the place in fabric.js code where you draw. Add a check if(this_pixel_is_black){ don't do anything }else{ draw the pixel.. }
2. Make a (PHP) script that goes through every pixel of the source image. If it's a black pixel, it will be drawn on a new transparent canvas. Save that image, and add it on top of the other fabric.js image. Then, when the user draws, it should draw it BELOW the transparent canvas on top.

Do you have any better ideas? And I don't know how to implement the two suggestions I had.

Comment: just general idea - what about using 3 layers(canvas): background with black color removed, drawing layer, and top layer with only black color from background. In this way draw whatever you want on second layer, black color will always be on top.

Comment: @ViliusL this was also the solution I suggested as "solution 2". And eventually the solution I implemented. It works great! See my below answer for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself using suggestion 2 in the OP.

Looked through the fabric.js source and noticed the method `_finalizeAndAddPath` that fires on mouseUp after having drawn. That method fires an event `path:created`.

When making a fabric.js canvas, I first create the "background" image, then I (via a PHP script) create a transparent image with only the black pixels filled.

When the `path:created` event is thrown, I move the drawn path backwards, so the transparent layer is still on top. It actually works really really great!

You can see a working JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2u4h4/

If anyone is interested in the PHP script that translates the image to a transparent png with only the black pixels, it's here:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('source.png');
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

//Placeholder to transparent image
$img_transp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

//Make image transparent (on white)
$index = imagecolorexact($img_transp, 255, 255, 255); 
imagecolortransparent($img_transp, $index); 
imagefill($img_transp, 0, 0, $index);

$black = imagecolorallocate($img_transp, 0, 0, 0);

//Loop every pixel
for($x = 0;$x < $width;$x++){
    for($y = 0;$y < $height;$y++){
        if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $y) == 0){ //Is the pixel black?
            imagesetpixel($img_transp, $x, $y, $black); //Draw the black pixel
        }
    }
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img_transp); //Show the image to the user
```